# I am trying to create a simple search, on click of a search button it should redirect to new component .but redirect is not at all working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In this method i am changing the state

```
showAlert() {
    if(this.state.userInput) {
      this.setState(() => ({
        toMyList: true
      }))
  }
```

In render method if state is changed. i am redirecting to my new component

```
render() {


     const { toMyList } = this.state


      if (this.state.toMyList === true) {
        return <Redirect push to="/MyList" />;
      }
    }
```

I am calling showalert() method on click of my button.

```
<button class="btn-search" type="button" onClick={() => {this.showAlert()}}>
              Search
            </button>
```

Do i have to make any changes in index.js to make react router work?
my current index.js is:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: What routing library are you using?

Comment: @Phobos i am using react-router-dom.

Comment: Please share what the route definition about the "MyList" .Like this <Route to="/MyList" component={...}/> @AbhilashK

Comment: @Root i have not  written an route definition, where should i write it ?

Comment: @AbhilashK You can read about how to set up your routing here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic. You are currently trying to route to an endpoint that isn't registered in your application.

Comment: @AbhilashK It's not convenient to write code in comment,so I made an answer for you.

Comment: @Root Thanks for your help, i added route definition in my index.js and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route definition about the "MyList" should in where you define the route structure.Like this in App.js or somewhere else that you defined it:

```
 render (){
    return (
      <div>
         <Router>
           <div>
             <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={IndexPage} />
              <Route path="/MyList" exact component={MyList}/>
             </Switch>
           </div>
         </Router>
      </div>
   )    
 }
```